# Docker-compose Start command throwing "No volume error"

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, joomla

I am working on deploying a Joomla application on a Linux server using Docker. When I use the docker-compose start command, I get the following error:

**Error**

```
"Cannot start service joomla-1: get 7bc8fef95dc63f2c845e57c3b5be68cb872179c02b0db8eeed5468e57cce1484: no such volume"
```

I have checked the images are available.

This was working properly before, but suddenly stopped working. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding your container? try it by `docker container prune` and then `docker-compose up`

Comment: Please add  * Your host OS and version * The docker-compose.yml fille * The commands you used to run the container, and any relevant output you saw (masking sensitive information)

Comment: I ran the below command,

/usr/local/bin/docker-compose start

Starting deep-haproxy ... done
Starting deep-haproxy-exporter ... done
Starting deep-solr ... done
Starting deep-mysql-joomladb ... done
Starting deep-joomla-1 ... error

ERROR: for deep-joomla-1  Cannot start service deep-joomla-1: get 7bc8fef95dc63f2c845e57c3b5be68cb872179c02b0db8eeed5468e57cce1484: no such volume

out of 5 containers, 4 started but the Joomla Container throws error.
I am unable to post .yaml as it is too long. When i checked i can see all the volumes in place. Can this be an issue of Permission?

Comment: @HamidAli Thanks a lot, your suggestion helped.

Comment: nice! @DanielRaj I am posting it as answer please feel free to upvote it so that other can follow this solution too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong with the container Volume. Try to delete your container first and then create it again.

```
docker container prune
```

and then

```
docker-compose up
```